# Unable to call a react native function

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to open my gallery from inside a bottom sheet. 
Broken down this is a problem that I don't know how to call functions in `React-native`.

So here is my Bottom Sheet

```
BottomSheet.showBottomSheetWithOptions({
  options: ['Gallery', 'Camera'],
  title: 'Choose attachment',
  dark: false,
  cancelButtonIndex: 3,
}, (value) => {
     switch (value) {
       case 0:
         this._onOpenGallery()
         break
       case 1:
         console.log("Option 2");
         break
       }
     })
```

which as you see tries to call `_onOpenGallery()`

which is:

```
  _onOpenGallery = () => {
    if (__DEV__) {console.log("gallery")}
    ImagePicker.openPicker({
      width: 300,
      height: 300,
      cropping: true,
      includeBase64: false,
    }).then(image => {

    }
  )
}
```

I've tried loads of combinations but always get _this4._onOpenGallery is not a function.

How can this be performed? calling this_onOpenGallery does not run the function

Answer (score 0):

It seems like **this** is not visible in your scope. Try to bind **this** to your function or add global function.

Comment: this._onOpenGallery.bind(this)
Gives cannot read property bind of undefined

Comment: try smth like BottomSheet.showBottomSheetWithOptions.bind(this).({}) or BottomSheet.showBottomSheetWithOptions.({}).bind(this)